# Fileobject passing threw csv reader Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Sample fileobject data contains the following,

```
b'QmFyY29kZSxRdHkKQTIzMjMsMTAKQTIzMjQsMTUKNjUxMDA1OTUzMjkyNSwxMgpBMjMyNCwxCkEyMzI0LDEKQTIzMjMsMTAK'
```

And python file contains the following code

```
string_data = BytesIO(base64.decodestring(csv_rec))
read_file = csv.reader(string_data, quotechar='"', delimiter=',')
next(read_file)
```

when i run the above code in python, i got the following exception

> _csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not int (did you open the file in text mode?)

How can i open a bytes data in text mode ?

Comment: If iterator should return strings, why not use `io.StringIO`? Like this: `string_data = StringIO(base64.decodestring(csv_rec).decode())`

Comment: Indeed, @9dogs. You should write an answer.

Comment: @9dogs You saved my day, thank you so much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are almost there. Indeed, `csv.reader` expects iterator which returns strings (not bytes). Such iterator is provided by sibling of `BytesIO` - `io.StringIO`.

```
from io import StringIO
csv_rec = b'QmFyY29kZSxRdHkKQTIzMjMsMTAKQTIzMjQsMTUKNjUxMDA1OTUzMjkyNSwxMgpBMjMyNCwxCkEyMzI0LDEKQTIzMjMsMTAK'

bytes_data = base64.decodestring(csv_rec)
# decode() method is used to decode bytes to string
string_data = StringIO(bytes_data.decode())
read_file = csv.reader(string_data, quotechar='"', delimiter=',')
next(read_file)
```

Comment: That `StringIO` is a lifesaver. I can't find that ANYWHERE in the documentation for a FileField in flask-wtf